# VeraCrypt Gui Setup Problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia

[ISSUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwNPD.png)

I am trying to install veracrypt to decrypt some of my documents when i was using the Windows. But when i try to install gui of Veracrypt this error comes along and when i search for VeraCrypt program in my OS there is no sign of Veracrypt at all.

I have tried this at terminal

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unit193/encryption
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install veracrypt

Veracrypt installed but i cant find any program named VeraCrypt to use on my volume documents.

Comment: have you checked on the command line ? `veracrypt` should open the gui

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

see if verarypt is on the path:

```
which veracrypt
```

if it is, invoke the binary:

```
veracrypt
```

if not, something went wrong with your installation so you may need to check dpkg's logs:

```
sudo cat /var/log/dpkg.log
```